# Call/generate dynamic javascript from silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I'm not sure this is supported but wanted to see if any of you had come up with something creative to work around this.

Is there a way to call javascript from silverlight, *without* having to define any javascript functions on the aspx page/external js?

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("(function () { window.lastErrorMessage = 'foo'; })();")
```

Which, to forgo conversations about style, I'd agree goes against many best practices rules, but my current purpose is brainstorm some quick-and-dirty error reporting (could you even call it reporting?) before we implement the existing database-centric error logging in this solution.

Any thoughts? The idea is to generate something discreet that a user wouldn't feel intruded upon or something too technical (like IE's script error dialog), but something our app support could get a little more info from without access to code bases etc.

Thanks, Matthew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `Eval` not `Invoke`:-

```
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("(function () { window.lastErrorMessage = 'foo'; })();")
```

Comment: +1: I had a typo that meant I did not get Eval to work, hence the longer workaround. *sigh* :)

Comment: can i -1 on google for not bringing this to my attention earlier? :) That's exactly what i was looking for - googling "silverlight call javascript" always brings up invoke - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could add your JavaScript dynamically to the hosting page DOM using HtmlPage.Document and then execute your added methods. *Or are you trying not to modify the page at all?*

```
            HtmlElement head = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0] as HtmlElement;
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = HtmlPage.Document;
            HtmlElement scriptElement = htmlDocument.CreateElement("script");
            scriptElement.SetAttribute("type", @"text/javascript");
            scriptElement.SetProperty("text", "function testMe(p) { alert(p); }");
            head.AppendChild(scriptElement);
            // Invoke like this
            HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("testMe", "hello");
```

Comment: +1: this is still cool enough I may use it somewhere else. I use jQuery so much i forget that modifying the DOM is a normal part of web dev life.